# Integral converges only if Mathematica kernel has just started?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, warning-messages

After just starting Mathematica (or quitting the kernel) if I run:

```
ClearAll[r, m, e]
e = Integrate[(Sinc[p r] - 1) p^2/(p^2 + m^2), {p, 0, Infinity}];
Assuming[ r > 0 && m > 0, Simplify[e]]
```

I get:

```
1/2 \[Pi] (m + E^(-m r)/r)
```

but it seems that if I happen to evaluate this cell again, I get a non-convergent integral error:

[image: error output]

I am using Mathematica 11.2.0 for mac.  I don't see anything stateful in this small calculation that would make the integral converge one time, but not the other -- any idea what's going on?

Comment: I get the same thing (1/2 \[Pi] (m + E^(-m r)/r)) each time I run it. Perhaps you have set some variable in between?

Comment: What is your version? On version 11.3, the result is repeated 1/2 \[Pi] (m + E^(-m r)/r)

Comment: @bill s, I didn't do anything in between.

Comment: @Alex Trounev.  my version is: 11.2.0 (stated in the question).

Comment: I can reproduce this on 10.4.1 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit).

Comment: On repeated evaluations I get the same result over and over again. I'd recommend upgrading...

Comment: With version 8.0, I never get convergence.

Comment: It doesn't seem that the integral should converge for `r > 0 && m > 0` since 

`Limit[(Sinc[p r] - 1) p^2/(p^2 + m^2), p -> Infinity, 
 Assumptions -> r > 0 && m > 0]` evaluates to 

`-1` and `Integrate[(Sinc[p r] - 1) p^2/(p^2 + m^2), {p, 0, Infinity}, 
 Assumptions -> r > 0 && m > 0]` indicates a failure to converge. (v11.3)